# JavaScript - Can I get the parent object of a method?

Tags: javascript, object, this

I was wondering whether I could get the parent object of a method - something like this:

```
ImageAsset = function (path) {
    this.ready = false; // I want the image.onload function to change this variable.

    this.image = new Image;
    this.image.onload = function () {
        thisParent.ready = true;
    };

    this.path = path;

    this.image.src = this.path;
};
```

Is there any way that I could do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you use a variable

```
ImageAsset = function (path) {

    var that = this; // store the value of "this"

    this.ready = false;

    this.image = new Image;

    this.image.onload = function () {
        that.ready = true;
    };

    this.path = path;

    this.image.src = this.path;
};
```

Comment: @jcaron - Yup, just noticed that the OP somehow added a property ?

Comment: That's clever - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

```
ImageAsset = function (path) {
    this.ready = false; // I want the image.onload function to change this variable.

    this.image = new Image;
    var parent = this;
    this.image.onload = function () {
        parent.ready = true;
    };

    this.path = path;

    this.image.src = this.path;
};
```

Comment: That's clever - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways to do this.

**You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the executing scope of your function to "parent".**

```
this.image.onload = function () {
        this.parent.ready = true;
 }.bind(this);
```

Note, `bind` is only available for [certain browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility).  So you'll proabaly want to use a  [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) so you can use bind in all browsers.  Also, many Javascript frameworks provide equivalents of the `bind` function.  For example, [jQuery provides proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/).

```
this.image.onload = $.proxy(function () {
    this.parent.ready;
}, this);
```

**Make a "parent" [closed over variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).**

```
var parent = this;
this.image.onload = function () {
    parent.ready = true;
};
```

Personally, I tend to go with option 1.